# BIO_set_cipher how using

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

How correct using

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

BIO_METHOD *   BIO_f_cipher(void);
```

I search example of symetric encrypt decrypt using **BIO_f_cipher()** and BIO_set_cipher()

I need C example bio_f_cipher because it not apear in manual.

Comment: Also, there are many posts with use cases for `BIO_set_cipher()` on SO, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26971590/9014097).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk link not have any example